# Android design Library AppBar scrolling behavior enterAlways

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using the latest version of the design support library (23.1.1) and I am facing an issue when I use the CollapsingToolbarLayout with the `enterAlways` scroll flag. Basically, when you scroll back up, the view appears but if also leaves a empty white space at top.

Normal View:

[image: Normal Image view]

After scrolling down and then back up (notice the whitespace below status bar):
[image]

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppBarLayout appBar;
    View expandedView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("");

        initViews();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private void initViews() {
        appBar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(appBarOffsetChangedListener);

        expandedView = findViewById(R.id.expandedView);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rv.setAdapter(new DummyAdapter());
    }

    private AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener appBarOffsetChangedListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            int maxOffset = appBar.getTotalScrollRange();
            verticalOffset = Math.abs(verticalOffset);
            if(verticalOffset > maxOffset)
                return;
            float percentage = verticalOffset / (float) maxOffset;

            if(expandedView!=null)
                expandedView.setAlpha(1 - percentage);
        }
    };
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.media2359.fragmenttoolbarchange.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandedView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/toolbar_text_margin_left"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_text_margin_top"
                tools:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_text_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_text_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text="04 Feb, Tuesday evening" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_dummy" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Using `enterAlwaysCollapsed` along with `enterAlways` avoids this issue but I want the full view to come back because in the actual app, the expanded section is way smaller.

Another thing that I have noticed is that, the height of the whitespace is equal to the height to the toolbar.

**EDIT 1**

I replaced `exitUntilCollapsed` with `snap` and then there wasn't any white space but then the toolbar doesn't pin and scrolls away

**EDIT 2**

Looks like this is an issue with the Design Library: [CollapsingToolbarLayout enterAlways not supported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193744)

Temporary Workaround: [Cheesesquare: enterAlways produces wrong layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33265541/759911)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that's because of:

```
enterAlways
```

Which the [`codepath/android_guides`](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) says:

> `enterAlways`: The view **will become visible when scrolling up**. ***This flag
>   is useful in cases when scrolling from the bottom of a list and
>   wanting to expose the Toolbar as soon as scrolling up takes place.***

Maybe you wanna try this: (standard way)

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

Honestly, I didn't see somebody is using `enterAlways` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in my whole development life.Especially, with those two flags:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways"
```

Otherwise, It could be a bug and needs the **Google**'s staffs to answer about it.

Comment: But that is exactly what I am trying to achieve, `expose the Toolbar as soon as scrolling up takes place.` I am not sure why it is an issue to use the three of them together. `scroll` to ask it to scroll, `exitUntilCollapsed ` to always keep toolbar in view

Comment: I see, but what happened when you tried these two?: `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed` same results? i said that because there is no implementation about those three flags.

Comment: as expected, that disables quick return, i.e. the view only comes back once I have scrolled back to the top of the list.

Comment: I replaced exitUntilCollapsed with snap and then there wasn't any white space but then the toolbar doesn't pin and scrolls away

Comment: I'm using exactly like your try with `snap` and `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`, it's working, not sure what causes but maybe you wanna report that to google and see what they say.

Comment: I edited the question to include a link to a open issue with Google. Looks like it is a bug with the library

Comment: Yeah, i felt that.Something like my question :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995278/size-of-shareaction-icon-issue-on-actionbar-with-shareactionprovider-v7